# Can neural network make from Small images make big

Tags: neural-network

I have several images of one artist, but they are small size 300x200 px
can Neural Network somehow restore it to a big size like 1024x768 if, for example, I have only one big picture from this artist?

Comment: I think this question needs some refining to make it answerable on this site, as neural networks can do quite a lot of things - probably it would work as a question it you researched a bit and asked a more involved question about how a particular approach worked. In the meantime, you could try looking at https://github.com/alexjc/neural-enhance - I don't know of anything that will do super-resolution of one image using a second image to refine the results - it is probably theoretically possible, but would need to be built to do just that.

Comment: Yes, there are many papers on this subject. Search for "(single-image) super-resolution".